# optimal creation of new columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a large data set. I need to get new columns based on the following sample

I have a table of the following type:

| ID | Column B | Column С |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 2 | 12 |
| 3 | 4 | 40 |
| 4 | 3 | 4 |

must be converted to the form:

| ID | Column B | Column С | col 1 | col 2 | col 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 3 | NaN | NaN | NaN |
| 2 | 6 | 12 | 4 | NaN | NaN |
| 3 | 8 | 36 | 9 | 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 7 | 4 | 0,33 | 1,33 | NaN |

It is necessary for each object (ID) to calculate the difference of the current value of Column C to the previous value. If there is no previous value, specify Nan.
Example for ID = 3:
col 1: 36/4 = 9 (the current value in column C is 36 the previous value is 4 (the previous value is determined by column B. The current value in column b = 8 means the previous one is 7)
col  2: 36/12 = 3
col 3: 36/3 = 12

I tried to translate the data into pandas and perform transformations, but this approach was not productive. how can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `shift()` method to create columns with shifted values like so:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"Column B": [1,2,4,3], "Column C": [3,12,36,4]})
df["C-1"] = df["Column C"].shift(-1)
df["C+1"] = df["Column C"].shift(1)
df["C+2"] = df["Column C"].shift(2)
df["col 1"] = df["Column C"]/df["C-1"]
df["col 2"] = df["Column C"]/df["C+1"]
df["col 3"] = df["Column C"]/df["C+2"]
print(df)
```

which produces the following output:

```
   Column B  Column C   C-1   C+1   C+2     col 1     col 2      col 3
0         1         3  12.0   NaN   NaN  0.250000       NaN        NaN
1         2        12  36.0   3.0   NaN  0.333333  4.000000        NaN
2         4        36   4.0  12.0   3.0  9.000000  3.000000  12.000000
3         3         4   NaN  36.0  12.0       NaN  0.111111   0.333333
```